# Analysis of betweenness in Gephi and R

Tags: r, gephi

I'm trying to analyze a network (*les miserables*) from the betweenness point of view.

A piece of the network is:

```
graph
[
  node
  [
    id 0
    label "Myriel"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  node
  [
    id 1
    label "Napoleon"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  node
  [
    id 2
    label "MlleBaptistine"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  node
  [
    id 3
    label "MmeMagloire"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  node
  [
    id 4
    label "CountessDeLo"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  node
  [
    id 5
    label "Geborand"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  node
  [
    id 6
    label "Champtercier"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  node
  [
    id 7
    label "Cravatte"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  node
  [
    id 8
    label "Count"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  node
  [
    id 9
    label "OldMan"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  node
  [
    id 10
    label "Labarre"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  node
  [
    id 11
    label "Valjean"
    maincharacter 1
  ]
  node
  [
    id 12
    label "Marguerite"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  node
  [
    id 13
    label "MmeDeR"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  node
  [
    id 14
    label "Isabeau"
    maincharacter 0
  ]
  ...
```

I open the network in Gephi and I made biggeer nodes using the "centrality Betweenness" attribute.
Doing it I get that the node of id 11 is the one with greater betweenness.

Then I tried to do the same thing in R.
So I run these commands:

```
> net <- read.graph("./dataset/lesmiserables.gml", format = c("gml"))

> bet <- betweenness(net, normalized = TRUE)
> print(bet)
 [1] 0.1768421053 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
 [9] 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.5699890528 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
[17] 0.0406293482 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.1296445410
[25] 0.0290024187 0.0749012212 0.0237962535 0.0543315597 0.0264912281 0.0080409357 0.0000000000 0.0086402950
[33] 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0069254386
[41] 0.0000000000 0.0114875507 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0263157895
[49] 0.1651125024 0.0202106216 0.0002172097 0.0475989279 0.0003508772 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.1320324886
[57] 0.0000000000 0.0276612364 0.0425533568 0.0012501456 0.0000000000 0.0012501456 0.0052670299 0.0021854883
[65] 0.0307536502 0.0021854883 0.0001503759 0.0000000000 0.0049603840 0.0049603840 0.0048618042 0.0038738299
[73] 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0004385965 0.0000000000
> max(bet)
[1] 0.5699891

> betValjean <- betweenness(net, v = 11, normalized = TRUE)
> print(betValjean)
[1] 0
```

Why in Gephi the node with the highest betweenness is the the node of 11 while in R the node with the highest betweenness is the node of id 12?

Why in R the node with id 11 has betweenness = 0?

I don't understand where I'm wrong..

Thank you all

Comment: In Gephi are you looking at node names or node ids?  The indexing by node may be different depending on which option you're using.

Comment: @jalapic Hi, thanks for the reply. In Gephi I simply clicked on Statistics-Avg path length and then I colored and the size based on the attribute nodes "Betweenness centrality".
I did see the node labels and saw that the largest node is Valjean with id 11. I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the id's of the vertices when you've read the graph in `igraph` do not necessarily correspond to the ids in your file. You don't specify how you've read the info in R, but assuming that you've done something like this,

```
net <- read.graph("lesmiserables.gml", format="gml")
```

and also assuming that I've found in google the same file as you, indeed when I calculate betweenness of node 11 I don't get the expected result,

```
> betValjean <- betweenness(net, v = 11, normalized = TRUE)
> betValjean
[1] 0
```

However node 11 is not Jean Valjean,

```
> get.vertex.attribute(net, "label", 11)
[1] "Labarre"
```

You can get the node you want like this,

```
> V(net)[label == "Valjean"]
+ 1/77 vertex:
[1] 12
```

And then the betweenness in any of this 3 ways:

```
> betweenness(net, v =V(net)[label == "Valjean"], normalized = TRUE)
[1] 0.5699891
> betweenness(net, v = V(net)[id == 11], normalized = TRUE)
[1] 0.5699891
> betweenness(net, v = 12, normalized = TRUE)
[1] 0.5699891
```

Hope it helps.